# Matplotlib Affine2D object has no attribute 'skew_deg'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot using `matplotlib` but I get an error, and after hours of searching, I do not see an alternative or something that works. Here's the code that's giving me trouble:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms        
self.transDataToAxes = self.transScale + (self.transLimits +
                transforms.Affine2D().skew_deg(rot, 0))
```

Which gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'Affine2D' object has no attribute 'skew_deg'`. This error happens with both python 2.7 and python 3.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I can try, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the entire script which I am trying to run, it should also be noted that I've tried this on Windows, Linux, and Mac with no success:

```
import matplotlib
spc_file = open('1OUN.txt', 'r').read()

import sharppy
import sharppy.sharptab.profile as profile
import sharppy.sharptab.interp as interp
import sharppy.sharptab.winds as winds
import sharppy.sharptab.utils as utils
import sharppy.sharptab.params as params
import sharppy.sharptab.thermo as thermo

import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

def parseSPC(spc_file):
    ## read in the file
    data = np.array([l.strip() for l in spc_file.split('\n')])

    ## necessary index points
    title_idx = np.where( data == '%TITLE%')[0][0]
    start_idx = np.where( data == '%RAW%' )[0] + 1
    finish_idx = np.where( data == '%END%')[0]

    ## create the plot title
    data_header = data[title_idx + 1].split()
    location = data_header[0]
    time = data_header[1][:11]

    ## put it all together for StringIO
    full_data = '\n'.join(data[start_idx : finish_idx][:])
    sound_data = StringIO( full_data )

    ## read the data into arrays
    p, h, T, Td, wdir, wspd = np.genfromtxt( sound_data, delimiter=',', comments="%", unpack=True )

    return p, h, T, Td, wdir, wspd

pres, hght, tmpc, dwpc, wdir, wspd = parseSPC(spc_file)

prof = profile.create_profile(profile='default', pres=pres, hght=hght, tmpc=tmpc, \
                                    dwpc=dwpc, wspd=wspd, wdir=wdir, missing=-9999, strictQC=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(prof.tmpc, prof.hght, 'r-')
plt.plot(prof.dwpc, prof.hght, 'g-')
#plt.barbs(40*np.ones(len(prof.hght)), prof.hght, prof.u, prof.v)
plt.xlabel("Temperature [C]")
plt.ylabel("Height [m above MSL]")
plt.grid()
plt.show()

msl_hght = prof.hght[prof.sfc] # Grab the surface height value
agl_hght = interp.to_agl(prof, msl_hght) # Converts to AGL
msl_hght = interp.to_msl(prof, agl_hght) # Converts to MSL

plt.plot(thermo.ktoc(prof.thetae), prof.hght, 'r-', label='Theta-E')
plt.plot(prof.wetbulb, prof.hght, 'c-', label='Wetbulb')
plt.xlabel("Temperature [C]")
plt.ylabel("Height [m above MSL]")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()

sfcpcl = params.parcelx( prof, flag=1 ) # Surface Parcel
#fcstpcl = params.parcelx( prof, flag=2 ) # Forecast Parcel
#mupcl = params.parcelx( prof, flag=3 ) # Most-Unstable Parcel
#mlpcl = params.parcelx( prof, flag=4 ) # 100 mb Mean Layer Parcel


# This serves as an intensive exercise of matplotlib's transforms
# and custom projection API. This example produces a so-called
# SkewT-logP diagram, which is a common plot in meteorology for
# displaying vertical profiles of temperature. As far as matplotlib is
# concerned, the complexity comes from having X and Y axes that are
# not orthogonal. This is handled by including a skew component to the
# basic Axes transforms. Additional complexity comes in handling the
# fact that the upper and lower X-axes have different data ranges, which
# necessitates a bunch of custom classes for ticks,spines, and the axis
# to handle this.

from matplotlib.axes import Axes
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.axis as maxis
import matplotlib.spines as mspines
import matplotlib.path as mpath
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

# The sole purpose of this class is to look at the upper, lower, or total
# interval as appropriate and see what parts of the tick to draw, if any.
class SkewXTick(maxis.XTick):
    def draw(self, renderer):
        if not self.get_visible(): return
        renderer.open_group(self.__name__)

        lower_interval = self.axes.xaxis.lower_interval
        upper_interval = self.axes.xaxis.upper_interval

        if self.gridOn and transforms.interval_contains(
                self.axes.xaxis.get_view_interval(), self.get_loc()):
            self.gridline.draw(renderer)

        if transforms.interval_contains(lower_interval, self.get_loc()):
            if self.tick1On:
                self.tick1line.draw(renderer)
            if self.label1On:
                self.label1.draw(renderer)

        if transforms.interval_contains(upper_interval, self.get_loc()):
            if self.tick2On:
                self.tick2line.draw(renderer)
            if self.label2On:
                self.label2.draw(renderer)

        renderer.close_group(self.__name__)


# This class exists to provide two separate sets of intervals to the tick,
# as well as create instances of the custom tick
class SkewXAxis(maxis.XAxis):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        maxis.XAxis.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.upper_interval = 0.0, 1.0

    def _get_tick(self, major):
        return SkewXTick(self.axes, 0, '', major=major)

    @property
    def lower_interval(self):
        return self.axes.viewLim.intervalx

    def get_view_interval(self):
        return self.upper_interval[0], self.axes.viewLim.intervalx[1]


# This class exists to calculate the separate data range of the
# upper X-axis and draw the spine there. It also provides this range
# to the X-axis artist for ticking and gridlines
class SkewSpine(mspines.Spine):
    def _adjust_location(self):
        trans = self.axes.transDataToAxes.inverted()
        if self.spine_type == 'top':
            yloc = 1.0
        else:
            yloc = 0.0
        left = trans.transform_point((0.0, yloc))[0]
        right = trans.transform_point((1.0, yloc))[0]

        pts  = self._path.vertices
        pts[0, 0] = left
        pts[1, 0] = right
        self.axis.upper_interval = (left, right)


# This class handles registration of the skew-xaxes as a projection as well
# as setting up the appropriate transformations. It also overrides standard
# spines and axes instances as appropriate.
class SkewXAxes(Axes):
    # The projection must specify a name.  This will be used be the
    # user to select the projection, i.e. ``subplot(111,
    # projection='skewx')``.
    name = 'skewx'

    def _init_axis(self):
        #Taken from Axes and modified to use our modified X-axis
        self.xaxis = SkewXAxis(self)
        self.spines['top'].register_axis(self.xaxis)
        self.spines['bottom'].register_axis(self.xaxis)
        self.yaxis = maxis.YAxis(self)
        self.spines['left'].register_axis(self.yaxis)
        self.spines['right'].register_axis(self.yaxis)

    def _gen_axes_spines(self):
        spines = {'top':SkewSpine.linear_spine(self, 'top'),
                  'bottom':mspines.Spine.linear_spine(self, 'bottom'),
                  'left':mspines.Spine.linear_spine(self, 'left'),
                  'right':mspines.Spine.linear_spine(self, 'right')}
        return spines

    def _set_lim_and_transforms(self):
        """
        This is called once when the plot is created to set up all the
        transforms for the data, text and grids.
        """
        rot = 30

        #Get the standard transform setup from the Axes base class
        Axes._set_lim_and_transforms(self)

        # Need to put the skew in the middle, after the scale and limits,
        # but before the transAxes. This way, the skew is done in Axes
        # coordinates thus performing the transform around the proper origin
        # We keep the pre-transAxes transform around for other users, like the
        # spines for finding bounds
        self.transDataToAxes = self.transScale + (self.transLimits +
                transforms.Affine2D().skew_deg(rot, 0))

        # Create the full transform from Data to Pixels
        self.transData = self.transDataToAxes + self.transAxes

        # Blended transforms like this need to have the skewing applied using
        # both axes, in axes coords like before.
        self._xaxis_transform = (transforms.blended_transform_factory(
                    self.transScale + self.transLimits,
                    transforms.IdentityTransform()) +
                transforms.Affine2D().skew_deg(rot, 0)) + self.transAxes

# Now register the projection with matplotlib so the user can select
# it.
register_projection(SkewXAxes)

pcl = sfcpcl
# Create a new figure. The dimensions here give a good aspect ratio
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5875, 6.2125))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='skewx')
ax.grid(True)

pmax = 1000
pmin = 10
dp = -10
presvals = np.arange(int(pmax), int(pmin)+dp, dp)

# plot the moist-adiabats
for t in np.arange(-10,45,5):
    tw = []
    for p in presvals:
        tw.append(thermo.wetlift(1000., t, p))
    ax.semilogy(tw, presvals, 'k-', alpha=.2)

def thetas(theta, presvals):
    return ((theta + thermo.ZEROCNK) / (np.power((1000. / presvals),thermo.ROCP))) - thermo.ZEROCNK

# plot the dry adiabats
for t in np.arange(-50,110,10):
    ax.semilogy(thetas(t, presvals), presvals, 'r-', alpha=.2)

plt.title(' OAX 140616/1900 (Observed)', fontsize=14, loc='left')
# Plot the data using normal plotting functions, in this case using
# log scaling in Y, as dicatated by the typical meteorological plot
ax.semilogy(prof.tmpc, prof.pres, 'r', lw=2)
ax.semilogy(prof.dwpc, prof.pres, 'g', lw=2)
ax.semilogy(pcl.ttrace, pcl.ptrace, 'k-.', lw=2)

# An example of a slanted line at constant X
l = ax.axvline(0, color='b', linestyle='--')
l = ax.axvline(-20, color='b', linestyle='--')

# Disables the log-formatting that comes with semilogy
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(100,1000,10))
ax.set_ylim(1050,100)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.set_xlim(-50,50)
plt.show()
```

And the text file can be found here, before renaming it: [OUN_Sounding](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/exper/soundings/18061800_OBS/OUN.txt)

Comment: It would be nice, if you could add a little bit more context (e.g runnable function, import, etc) to your code. It will make your problem reproducable for others, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to follow tutorial(s) but none of them work here's the link to one: [SHARPpy Scriptin](https://github.com/sharppy/SHARPpy#scripting-with-sharppy) I can add the class to this, but not sure how much it will help. I did add an import statement that I left out though.

Comment: The code shown works fine for me. Which matplotlib version are you using? I suppose it is a very old one which does not have `skew_deg`? Otherwise you need to provide a [mcve], i.e. a code that is runnable and reproduces the error.

Comment: I am running version 2.2.2, which appears to be the latest version. I added the rest of the code to the question if anyone wants to take a look at that.